# How to avoid gap on javascript image carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use this javascript image [GridColumnCarousel](http://anysom.github.io/GridColumnCarousel/) - but I noticed, that in the example, there is a gap after the last image. First, you see the 4 images, when I click next, it shows me the remaining 2 images, but there is still space for 2 more images.So I wonder if it is possible to avoid that by making the carousel jump to the next 2 images and showing the previous 2, so that the gap is non existing. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Im sure it is possible. Or you could have 8 photos, or only show two on each page. He's using [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for the carousel so I would suggest looking at that to figure out your way around it, and bootstrap has its own carousel also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way. There is a plugin called slick. It will give you an infinite carousel. Click [here](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) for details.

Check example 6 to get an idea. Ill drop the example code here anyway:

```
<div data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 4, "slidesToScroll": 4}'>
  <div><h3>1</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2</h3></div>
  <div><h3>3</h3></div>
  <div><h3>4</h3></div>
  <div><h3>5</h3></div>
  <div><h3>6</h3></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I think this will fit to what I need! Thanks! :-)